# Dropdown won't close when clicking outside button/dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am having a little problem. If you look at the code snippet the dropdown is working a little different on the snippet than on my website. On my website you can search and everything works as it should. However when you have opened the dropdown and then click outside I want it to close, but it doesn't. I think it have something to do with the script. Would appreciate help.

```js
        function myFunction() {
          var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropdown'),
            items = dropDown.children,
            height = 0;
          dropDown.classList.toggle('show');
          for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            height += items[i].offsetHeight;
          }
          dropDown.style.height = height + 'px';
        }

        function filterFunction() {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
          a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
          for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              a[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
              a[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }

        var btn = document.querySelector('.dropbtn');

        btn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
          var dd = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
          if ( dd.classList.contains('show') ) {
            dd.classList.remove('show');
          }
        });
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 125px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">CARS</button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <a href="C:\Users\aleksar\Documents\Random\programmering\justcars.com\Cars\Acura\acura.html" href="#acura">Acura</a>
            <a href="alfa_romeo.html" href="#alfa romeo">Alfa Romeo</a>
            <a href="aston_martin.html" href="#aston martin">Aston Martin</a>
            <a href="audi.html" href="#audi">Audi</a>
            <a href="bentley.html" href="#bentley">Bentley</a>
            <a href="bmw.html" href="#bmw">BMW</a>
            <a href="bugatti.html" href="#bugatti">Bugatti</a>
            <a href="buick.html" href="#buick">Buick</a>
            <a href="cadillac.html" href="#cadillac">Cadillac</a>
            <a href="chevrolet.html" href="#chevrolet">Chevrolet</a>
            <a href="chrysler.html" href="#chrysler">Chrysler</a>
            <a href="dodge.html" href="#dodge">Dodge</a>
            <a href="ferrari.html" href="#ferrari">Ferrari</a>
            <a href="fiat.html" href="#fiat">Fiat</a>
            <a href="ford.html" href="#ford">Ford</a>
            <a href="gensis.html" href="#gensis">Gensis</a>
            <a href="gmc.html" href="#gmc">GMC</a>
            <a href="honda.html" href="#honda">Honda</a>
            <a href="hyundai.html" href="#custom">Hyundai</a>
            <a href="infiniti.html" href="#support">Infiniti</a>
            <a href="jaguar.html" href="#tools">Jaguar</a>
            <a href="jeep.html" href="#jeep">Jeep</a>
            <a href="kia.html" href="#kia">Kia</a>
            <a href="koenigsegg.html" href="#koenigsegg">Koenigsegg</a>
            <a href="lamborghini.html" href="#lamborghini">Lamborghini</a>
            <a href="land_rover.html" href="#land rover">Land Rover</a>
            <a href="lexus.html" href="#lexus">Lexus</a>
            <a href="lincoln.html" href="#lincoln">Lincoln</a>
            <a href="lotus.html" href="#lotus">Lotus</a>
            <a href="maserati.html" href="#maserati">Maserati</a>
            <a href="mazda.html" href="#mazda">Mazda</a>
            <a href="mclaren.html" href="#mclaren">McLaren</a>
            <a href="mercedes_amg.html" href="#mercedes-amg">Mercedes-AMG</a>
            <a href="mercedes_benz.html" href="#mercedes-benz">Mercedes-Benz</a>
            <a href="mercedes_maybach.html" href="#mercedes-maybach">Mercedes-Maybach</a>
            <a href="mini.html" href="#mini">Mini</a>
            <a href="mitsubishi.html" href="#mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</a>
            <a href="nissan.html" href="#nissan">Nissan</a>
            <a href="pagani.html" href="#pagani">Pagani</a>
            <a href="porsche.html" href="#porsche">Porsche</a>
            <a href="ram.html" href="#ram">Ram</a>
            <a href="rolls_royce.html" href="#rolls-royce">Rolls-Royce</a>
            <a href="scion.html" href="#scion">Scion</a>
            <a href="smart.html" href="#smart">Smart</a>
            <a href="spyker.html" href="#spyker">Spyker</a>
            <a href="subaru.html" href="#subaru">Subaru</a>
            <a href="tesla.html" href="#tesla">Tesla</a>
            <a href="toyota.html" href="#toyota">Toyota</a>
            <a href="volkswagen.html" href="#volkswagen">Volkswagen</a>
            <a href="volvo.html" href="#volvo">Volvo</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your example it closes. You sure there is a problem?

Comment: It does close both on Chrome and Firefox. Maybe the search input box is the problem: when clicked the menu closes

Comment: I know that it works on the code snippet, but it aren't working when I am opening the file from my documents. I have tried on both microsoft edge and chrome. @Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, with a document event listener for click, and e.stopPropagation() on any menu elements.

Also, why do you have two hrefs for each link?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropdown'),
        items = dropDown.children,
        height = 0;
    dropDown.classList.toggle('show');
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        height += items[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    dropDown.style.height = height + 'px';
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

var menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dd = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
    if (dd.classList.contains('show')) {
        dd.classList.remove('show');
    }
})
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px;
  height: 65px;
  width: 125px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lato', serif;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">CARS</button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <a href="acura.html" href="#acura">Acura</a>
            <a href="alfa_romeo.html" href="#alfa romeo">Alfa Romeo</a>
            <a href="aston_martin.html" href="#aston martin">Aston Martin</a>
            <a href="audi.html" href="#audi">Audi</a>
            <a href="bentley.html" href="#bentley">Bentley</a>
            <a href="bmw.html" href="#bmw">BMW</a>
            <a href="bugatti.html" href="#bugatti">Bugatti</a>
            <a href="buick.html" href="#buick">Buick</a>
            <a href="cadillac.html" href="#cadillac">Cadillac</a>
            <a href="chevrolet.html" href="#chevrolet">Chevrolet</a>
            <a href="chrysler.html" href="#chrysler">Chrysler</a>
            <a href="dodge.html" href="#dodge">Dodge</a>
            <a href="ferrari.html" href="#ferrari">Ferrari</a>
            <a href="fiat.html" href="#fiat">Fiat</a>
            <a href="ford.html" href="#ford">Ford</a>
            <a href="gensis.html" href="#gensis">Gensis</a>
            <a href="gmc.html" href="#gmc">GMC</a>
            <a href="honda.html" href="#honda">Honda</a>
            <a href="hyundai.html" href="#custom">Hyundai</a>
            <a href="infiniti.html" href="#support">Infiniti</a>
            <a href="jaguar.html" href="#tools">Jaguar</a>
            <a href="jeep.html" href="#jeep">Jeep</a>
            <a href="kia.html" href="#kia">Kia</a>
            <a href="koenigsegg.html" href="#koenigsegg">Koenigsegg</a>
            <a href="lamborghini.html" href="#lamborghini">Lamborghini</a>
            <a href="land_rover.html" href="#land rover">Land Rover</a>
            <a href="lexus.html" href="#lexus">Lexus</a>
            <a href="lincoln.html" href="#lincoln">Lincoln</a>
            <a href="lotus.html" href="#lotus">Lotus</a>
            <a href="maserati.html" href="#maserati">Maserati</a>
            <a href="mazda.html" href="#mazda">Mazda</a>
            <a href="mclaren.html" href="#mclaren">McLaren</a>
            <a href="mercedes_amg.html" href="#mercedes-amg">Mercedes-AMG</a>
            <a href="mercedes_benz.html" href="#mercedes-benz">Mercedes-Benz</a>
            <a href="mercedes_maybach.html" href="#mercedes-maybach">Mercedes-Maybach</a>
            <a href="mini.html" href="#mini">Mini</a>
            <a href="mitsubishi.html" href="#mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</a>
            <a href="nissan.html" href="#nissan">Nissan</a>
            <a href="pagani.html" href="#pagani">Pagani</a>
            <a href="porsche.html" href="#porsche">Porsche</a>
            <a href="ram.html" href="#ram">Ram</a>
            <a href="rolls_royce.html" href="#rolls-royce">Rolls-Royce</a>
            <a href="scion.html" href="#scion">Scion</a>
            <a href="smart.html" href="#smart">Smart</a>
            <a href="spyker.html" href="#spyker">Spyker</a>
            <a href="subaru.html" href="#subaru">Subaru</a>
            <a href="tesla.html" href="#tesla">Tesla</a>
            <a href="toyota.html" href="#toyota">Toyota</a>
            <a href="volkswagen.html" href="#volkswagen">Volkswagen</a>
            <a href="volvo.html" href="#volvo">Volvo</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have one so when you search some thing like ''mer'' and nothing more, Mercedes-Maybach, Mercedes-Benz and Mercedes-AMG comes up. The other one is for when you click it, you come to the site.